# Regex that does not allow zeros

Tags: regex

I use this regex:

```
/^(?!0000)(?!0+(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$)\d{1,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/
```

It allows decimal numbers (. and , separators), with two digits after the separator. It does not allow zero values. What I want to do is to make it allow numbers like 0.1 and 0.09 etc... Here it's impossible to write any number starting with 0. I don't know how to do this. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What language is it for?

Comment: Java. But it's not important.

Comment: Of course it is! The regex flavor are different from implementation to another! Also, a simple check of `Integer.parseInt(value) != 0` could do the work

Comment: Sorry it's for the front part, so javascript/angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regex with just one negative lookahead:

```
/^(?![,.0]*$)\d{1,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BGu8gK/1)

`(?![,.0]*$)` will prevent any input with just 0s, dots or commas in input.

Comment: I modified it for my use case to not allow .0 Ex 1.0 - Not allowed `^((?![.0]+)[0-9]{1,10}[.]?){1,7}$`

Comment: @Chinmoy: Good enhancement ++ If my answer helped you in anyway please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned JS/Angular, you may replace all `,` with `.` (in case the decimal separator is `,`) and cast the string to a number to check if it is zero, and if it is, then use your simplified regex `/^\d{1,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/` that makes sure there are 1 to 4 digits in the whole part and 1 to 2 digits in the fractional part:

```js
function check(str) {
  str = str.replace(/,/g, ".");
  if ( parseFloat(str) > 0 ) {
     return /^\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(str);
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(check("0,00"));
console.log(check("0,09"));
console.log(check("900000"));
```

**If you cannot access the code**, adjust the negative lookahead like

```
^(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)\d{1,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJb9TU/1)

The `(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)` negative lookahead fails the match only if the string starts with 1 or more zeros, and then has an optional sequence of `,` or `.` followed with 1 or more zeros.

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)` - reject the match if it matches a sequence of

  - `0+` - 1 or more zeros
  - `(?:[.,]0+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` or `,` followed with 1 or more zeros
- `\d{1,4}` - 1 to 4 digits
- `(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[.,]` - a `.` or `,`
  - `\d{1,2}` - any 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

The lookahead pattern may be reduced to `(?!0*[.,]?0+$)`, since the consuming pattern will ensure the correct format is matched.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: @Anna Just in case you are interested, I added a more JS oriented solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any regex based approach would be trivial to bypass. For example, they could use any of the following to evade your regex filter:

- `+0`- Start with `+`
- `-0` - Start with `-`
- `0e0` - Scientific notation
- `1e-999` - Not real 0, but most likely will be one after conversion.

And any combination of methods above.
Long story short: regex wouldn't work here.
Try to cast your string to a number and reject if it equals to 0.
You should be able to do that in most languages, including JavaScript.